# mingw32 g++ and stdcall @suffix

Tags: c++, linker, mingw, name-decoration, stdcall

I declared some C++ functions prototyped as follows:

```
extern "C" void __stdcall function();
```

I also have some third-party dll with exported `function()` - no name decorations at all. 
I'm unable to build my exe or dll due to `undefined reference to function@...`, because of MinGW's stdcall @-suffix. How can I obtain object file without @... just plain function names?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're trying to use MinGW to compile a program that uses external C functions from a third-party dll. There's a way to export those external functions into a proper import library that MinGW's `gnu ld` linker can use but it involves creating a `.def` definition file. The advantage with this is once you create a proper import library you won't have to fiddle around with switches like `--add-stdcall-alias` or `--kill-at` because the import library will contain the symbols expected by the compiler and linker.

Here's a rough outline of the procedure for doing this:

1. You'll need a tool call `dlltool.exe` which should be included in the same `MinGW/bin` directory as the compiler.
2. You'll need to create a definition file (*.def) listing all the external functions you're interested in importing.
3. Create the import file stub (*.a) by running dlltool passing in the .def file you created as input.
4. Pass the newly created import file *.a to the linker when building your project so the symbols can be resolved properly.

Here's how the definition file looks like:

```
;Run the dlltool like this:
;dlltool -k -d third_party.def -l libthird_party.a
LIBRARY third_party.dll

EXPORTS
    dll_function1@0
    dll_function2@8
    dll_function3@16
;   ...
    dll_function_n@24
```

Couple of important things to note. The `EXPORTS` section has to list the exported symbols/functions in the *same name-decorated format* as expected by the toolchain. In this case, MinGW compiler and ld linker expects `__stdcall` C functions to be appended with an '@' follow by the number of bytes in the arguments. The second important thing to note is that `dlltool -k` will remove the '@', which does the same thing as the `--kill-at` option you've already seen. The end result of this is you have an import library with the correct internal name-decoration, so things resolve properly, *and* that internal name will map to the exported visible name found in your 3<sup>rd</sup> party dll.

One final thing that needs mentioning. Throughout the entire example, we were *assuming* the undecorated names in the dll used the `__stdcall` which isn't necessarily true. The following chart([taken from here](http://www.willus.com/mingw/yongweiwu_stdcall.html)) shows how different compilers decorate `__cdecl` vs `__stdcall` differently:

```
                  MSVC DLL
Call Convention | (dllexport) | DMC DLL     | MinGW DLL  | BCC DLL
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
__stdcall       | _Function@n | _Function@n | Function@n | Function
__cdecl         | Function    | Function    | Function   | _Function
```

It's up to you to make sure that the call conventions match-up properly or risk stack corruption and mysterious program crashes.

Answer (score 5):

`man ld` gives you the  `--enable-stdcall-fixup` option for linking against non-@-decorated libraries. I'm not sure if the leading underscores will be a problem, you'll have to try.

If you want to produce object files or DLLs with mingw and want export names without the "@", `--kill-at` is your friend.

Comment: No, this not work. In addition, if I remember it right, stdcall fixups goes automatically if applicable and one has only to use --disable. What I'm looking for is removing @

Comment: When you want to link against @'s, that's what stdcall fixups are for. Or do you want to build a DLL with mingw and don't have the symbols exported with @'s?

Comment: As I stated before, I have some third party dll with exported function (and this function probably has to be called via stdcall - because it is used in some old VisualBasic sample) and no decorations at all and I wrote c++ extern function. What I actually need is object file without @-suffix. In this way I can test it twice: 1) execute via c++, 2) test my c++ intermediate in VisualBasic to eliminate some possible pointers-etc.-related issues. But nothing is working, I've tried g++ options, objcopy, ...

Comment: so one possibility is --add-stdcall-alias, this way one can obtain object without (and with) @-suffix. I've already tried it out, but it works only now (maybe linker's options goes last?)